# Drupal hook_user_update is not working

Tags: php, datetime, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-hooks

I want the last updated time of the user profile details. So i have created a table user_changes with fields ( id, uid, changed ). When i use this hook_user_update hook , then data is not inserted into the table. I'm using this function in my theme's template.php

```
function garland_user_update(&$edit, $account, $category) {
    db_insert('user_changes')->fields(array(
    'uid' => $account->uid,
    'changed' => time(),
    ))->execute();
    exit; 
}
```

Let me know if you want any details. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hooks must be implemented in modules, not in themes. For that, choose a name (e.g. `example`), create a directory by that name in `sites/all/modules`, create the `example.info` file with content

```
name = Example
description = Does some fancy stuff in certain situations
core = 7.x
```

in that directory and put your function in `sites/all/modules/example/example.module`. You also have to rename your function to `example_user_update`.

Further reading:

- [Writing module .info files (Drupal 7.x)](https://drupal.org/node/542202)
- [Understanding the hook system for Drupal modules](https://drupal.org/node/292)
- [`module_invoke_all`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_invoke_all/7), the function that is used to invoke hook implementations.

Comment: Hi Oswald, can you do me one more favour? i trust that you can easily fix this issue. I have posted this question yesterday only. can you check it ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23496574/drupal-dynamic-select-list-not-reterving-values-in-subcategory-field

Comment: If you need any more clarification, let me know